# Не сохранятются изменения в масиве

Tags: php, magento

Есть код

```
private function groupMessages($main) {
    foreach ($main as $storeProducts) {
        foreach ($storeProducts as $product) {
            $storeId = $product['store'];
            $product['store'] = $this->storeManager->getStore($storeId)->getCode();
        }
    }

    return array_filter($main);
}
```

Вот что получаю после изменений в массиве $product

```
'store' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'nnov3'</font> <i>(length=5)</i>
```

Однако в изначальном массиве изменения не сохранились

```
'store' <font color='#888a85'>=&gt;</font> <small>int</small> <font color='#4e9a06'>1</font>
```

Comment: Открывайте-читайте https://www.php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Можно это делать не используя ссылок? Если да, то как?

Comment: `foreach (as $key => $value) { $array[$key] = }`

Comment: Нет. Так не меняет

Comment: Я не телепат, приложите код.